# Which Alphabet type should I use with FASTA files in Biopython?

Tags: biopython

If I'm using the FASTA files from the link below, what Alphabet type should I use in Biopython? Would it be IUPAC.unambiguous_dna?

link to FASTA files: http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/chromosomes/?C=S;O=A

Comment: I would suggest asking on biostars.org, more likely to find a better answer there

Answer (score 1):

Did you read [3.1  Sequences and Alphabets](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc17)? It explains the different alphabets available, and what cases they cover.

There's a lot of sequences in the link you provided (too many for us to pore through). My recommendation would be to just go with `UnambiguousDNA`. If the four basic nucleotides aren't enough, the parser will complain, and you should pick a more extensive alphabet.